# won't replace connectionstring for release in msbuild

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I'm using msbuild 3.5, visual studio 2008, and web deployment projects.

I enabled webconfig replacement option for the web deployment project.

I thought I could do something like the following in the build script by appending another ItemGroup for release?

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <WebConfigReplacementFiles Include="webDebug.config">
        <Section>connectionStrings</Section>
    </WebConfigReplacementFiles>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU'">
    <WebConfigReplacementFiles Include="webRelease.config">
        <Section>connectionStrings</Section>
    </WebConfigReplacementFiles>
</ItemGroup>
<Import Project
```

I do the following just fine:

```
msbuild myProject.wdproj
```

and whatever I have for the Include attribute, whether it be webDebug or webRelease it will work for the Debug version.

How do I do the same for the Release version?

I tried the following:

```
msbuild myProj.wdproj /p:Configuration=Release
```

but the connection string is never replaced properly.

What can I try next?